# Microprofile JWT web.xml returns 200 instead of 401

Tags: java, jwt, jax-rs, payara, microprofile

i'm working on a small backend. To secure that thing I want to use JWT. 
My Tech-Stack is: Payara & Keycloak
Fortunately I found a great tutorial (https://kodnito.com/posts/microprofile-jwt-with-keycloak/)

Against the suggestion of the author I want to protect all endpoints underneath /resources/* by web.xml.

This is my web.xml:

```
...
<security-constraint>
        <display-name>App-Name</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>App-Name</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>mysimplerole</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>mysimplerole</role-name>
    </security-role>
...
```

So far so good. If I send a Request to a endpoint e.g. http://localhost:8080/resources/test
I receive a 401 as expected.

If I add @LoginConfig(authMethod = "MP-JWT") to my JAXRSConfiguration.java and call the endpoint again.
I receive a 200 but no content is sent, I would expect a 401 to come up. If I add a JWT-Token to my request, then the 200 + the expected content show up.

TestResource.java:

```
@Path("test")
public class TestResource {

    @GET
    public Response test() {
        return Response.ok("HI").build();
    }
}
```

JAXRSConfiguration.java

```
@ApplicationPath("/resources")
@LoginConfig(authMethod = "MP-JWT")
public class JAXRSConfiguration extends Application {

}
```

So the question is, what do I have to do to receive a 401 if no/or a invalid token is append to the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JAX-RS configuration class is missing the `@DeclareRoles({ "mysimplerole", "USER" })` annotation to specify all available roles in your application.

```
@ApplicationPath("/resources")
@LoginConfig(authMethod = "MP-JWT")
@DeclareRoles({ "mysimplerole", "USER" })
public class JAXRSConfiguration extends Application {

}
```